# Upgrading Python to 2.7 on OSX

Tags: python, macos

How can I upgrade Python from 2.6 to 2.7 on osx ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an installer for it [here](http://www.python.org/getit/).

Comment: Using the installer has given me all kinds of problems in the past when installing 3rd party modules with `easy_install` or `pip`. Also, it is difficult to switch to and from versions. I think using `macports` or `fink` is a safer option.

Comment: The trick is making sure you install a version of `easy_install` (from setuptools or Distribute) or `pip` for each version of Python you are using.  And it is easy to switch between versions with Python framework builds on Mac OS X: either change your shell $PATH or, easier, just use the versioned name: python2.6, python2.7, python3.2, etc.

Comment: You downvoted the answer because a 3 year old link is broken? I guess that makes sense as it has become incorrect. If I fix it, do I get an upvote?

Answer (score 9):

Visit this website and download the latest version for OS X (2.7.9 or 3.4.2) that you want. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Now open the DMG and execute the installer... this (Python.mpkg) will install the Python release into **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework**, which is not what we want, as the previously installed Python versions in **/usr/bin/python** may lead to some nasty incompatibilities. So in other words some work still needs to be done to really update Python on your Mac.

1. Open a terminal and enter:
   ***sudo rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7*** This will delete previously installed versions of Python 2.7.x
2. Now enter this into the terminal:
   ***sudo mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions*** 
   which moves the newly installed python 2.7.9 release next to the previous Python releases.

Further steps can be found here:
http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Comment: This seems like it is now more complicated, as per this link http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101328/file-cant-be-moved-by-root-on-os-x. I was unable to move anything to that folder

Answer (score 5):

Install [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/). It has a Python 2.7 port.

```
sudo port install python27
```

Comment: +1 for MacPorts. This also gives you the possibility to switch between versions of python, and more control when you install 3rd party python modules.

Answer (score 3):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) also has a Python 2.7 port.

```
brew install python
```

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7 is bundled with OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) and onwards, so it is likely that most Macs running today (2018) will have python 2.7 without any further effort.